# Interactive "r" elisp defun with additional args?

Tags: function, emacs, elisp, interactive

Is it possible to write an interactive defun with code "r" that has an additional optional argument (so that it does things within the selected region, but with another argument)? I would like something like the following:

```
(defun my-function (start end &optional arg)
  "Do something with selected region"
  (interactive "r")
  (if arg
      (setq val arg)
    (setq val 2))
  (do things...))
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Interactive-Codes.html) it says

> 'r': Point and the mark, as two numeric
>   arguments, smallest first. This is the
>   only code letter that specifies two
>   successive arguments rather than one.
>   No I/O.

I'm not sure if the 'No I/O' and 'two successive arguments' means that it takes 2 and only 2 arguments (i.e., limited to the region's start and end point as args). Although it allows me to evaluate and run the defun with an additional argument, Emacs appears to be ignoring it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make `interactive` ask for multiple parameters, separate them with a newline character. For instance, if you want your third parameter be bound to the value of the prefix argument, define your function like this:

```
(defun my-function (start end &optional arg)
  "Do something with selected region"
  (interactive "r\np")
  (if arg
      (setq val arg)
    (setq val 2))
  (do things...))
```

`M-x describe-function interactive` gives you further information.

Answer (score 1):

A function can be called in two ways:

- Interactively: This is what happens when a user calls the command, e.g. when it has been bound to a key.
- From lisp: When the function is called from another lisp function. e.g. `(r 100 200 t)`.

In your case, you have to make sure that the arguments match the *interactive specification*, in this case it must accept two arguments. The third will not be used when called interactively (so then it will get the value `nil`).

NO I/O means that it will not prompt the user for input (like it does when it asks for a file name).

If you want your function to act differently depending in when the region is active, you could ask the function `(use-region-p)`.